# TmongoDbInput schema not retrieving JsonArray Properly

Tags: mongodb, talend

I'm trying to retrieve below mongo collection data using TalendOpenStudio for Big Data 7.2.
T

{
"id": "5b69b66d3dae73000fa39440",

"data":"Testing"
"products": [{ "orderid":"1234"
}],
"createDate": "2018-08-07T15:10:37.570Z",
"updateDate": "2018-08-09T16:09:46.621Z"
}

I'm able to get Id,data but when i try to get products i'm unable to get the data. On top of it i'm getting products as below

[Document{{"orderid"="1234"}}] this is blocking me for parsing it as json. Can someone help. I think its a basic mistake but as i said i'm new to Talend OS for Big Data

If anyone has already parsed this , can you please share the schema to be defined for products arraylist in talend and how they parsed id,data,products.

I tried using extractjson fields, using mongoschema from repository still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a mongo driver(3.5.x) issue. Here are more details.

https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/TmongoDbInput-schema-not-retreiving-properly/m-p/202163#M110456